# How is the 'id' Field Handled by SQFlite Flutter Package During an Insert?

Tags: database, flutter, dart, sqflite, dart-null-safety

This question has to do with the [sqflite Flutter package](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite), the "id" field, and how that affects null safe coding choices in the data model.

Consider the following (working fine) code:

```
class User {
  final int? id;
  final String name;
  final int age;
  final String country;
  final String? email;

  User(
      { this.id,
      required this.name,
      required this.age,
      required this.country,
      this.email});

  User.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> res)
      : id = res["id"],
        name = res["name"],
        age = res["age"],
        country = res["country"],
        email = res["email"];

  Map<String, Object?> toMap() {
    return {'id':id,'name': name, 'age': age, 'country': country, 'email': email};
  }
}
```

So this is our User "model."

The toMap() function comes into play when we do the following (psuedo code):

```
User newUser = new User(...);

Database.insert(MY_TABLE, newUser.toMap());
```

Am I correct in the following:

- The reason that the User.id field is optional (nullable) is because it is actually the primary key in MY_TABLE and therefore pointless to define when creating a new user.
- When inserting a user, sqflite will either A) if id is null, generate a new id, then insert or B) if id is not null, attempt to insert using that id.

Or is it C) the id is always ignored and generated on insert?

I tried looking through the [source code](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite) but I can't find it the part I'm looking for.